# Jasmine Test for Sorting Function

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

I have some example data:

```
var jasmineData = [
  {
    "carrierName": "Mario Bros",
    "planName": "Rainbow Road",
    "copay": 100,
    "premium": 200,
    "annualLimit": 100000
  },
  {
    "carrierName": "Mega Man",
    "planName": "Dr. Whiley",
    "copay": 250,
    "premium": 1000,
    "annualLimit": 250000
  }
]
```

And a function that adds this data into a table:

```
function addDataToTable(jasmineData) {
  for(var plan in jasminenData){
    var endOfTable = $('.headers').after();
    endOfTable.append($('<tr class="remove_for_intial_sort"><td>' + jasminenData[plan].carrierName + '</td><td>' + jasminenData[plan].planName + '</td><td>' 
    + jasminenData[plan].copay +'</td><td>' + jasminenData[plan].premium + '</td><td>' + jasminenData[plan].annualLimit + '</td></tr>'))
  }
 };
```

Does anyone know a good way to approach this for testing? I was going to test the length of $('headers') but that didn't work.

Comment: The problem is that your function is void if it returns the HTML that would make more sense to test.

Comment: compare the difference of the number of `<tr>`s in endOfTable before and after adding, and see if it matches `jasmineData.length`?